# creating subclass of sklearn.tree._splitter.Splitter

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to write a subclass of sklearn.tree._splitter.Splitter, that implement my own node_split function, and I could really use an example for such a class.

However, I have only the *.pyd of the class. So subclasses like BestSplitter which appear in _splitter.pyx can't help me.

Have anyone wrote such a subclass, implementing it own node_split and using _splitter.pyd, and can upload an example?

I don’t care if the example is in python or cython, or how complicated it is. Any example will do.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?